# Preview PDF before save it

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, preview

I want to preview a PDF file.

I used `iTextSharp` in C# to generate the `PDF` file.

How can I make a function to `preview` PDF file before print it.

I didn't find anything on the `preview` with `iTextSharp`

Comment: You didn't find anything because iTextSharp isn't a PDF viewer. Your question sounds like: I want to watch TV on my radio. The answer is: don't watch TV on your radio, watch TV on a TV. Back to the topic: don't use iText to preview a PDF, use a tool that allows PDF viewing.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, do you know a tool to do a PDF viewing ?

Comment: What software are you printing the PDF with? I'm pretty sure whatever you use for printing also has the ability to view a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I did find an answer of my question and I want to shared it with all.

So, I have make a personnal viewer with Windows.Data.Pdf library.

Answer (score 0):

I would just open the By saving it the opening it then having a check to see if it is open and if it isn't open anymore deleting it.

```
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 20, 10);
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("submitted.pdf", FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
// do your generating code here
doc.Close();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("filepath\\submitted.pdf");
System.IO.File.Delete("filepath\\submitted.pdf");
```